# Run a function within a widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to run a function within a flutter widget without having to use *onpress* or *ontap* to activate or trigger them?

Basically, I just want to run a function or a small set of code in the background without having to display anything out on the application.

is there some sort of widget that would allow me to just run a function?

Answer (score 2):

There are no widget for running background functions, but something you could do is to utilize the lifecycle methods that stateful widgets have like initState

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

initState will fire once when an stateful widget is created. From there, you can start whatever background task you have.